# Generalization error bound in case of collaborative learning

Tags: learning-theory

I am reading the paper ["Collaborative PAC Learning"](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2017/hash/186a157b2992e7daed3677ce8e9fe40f-Abstract.html) by Blum et al. So I will try to setup the problem here as to avoid reading the complete section (personalized setting).

Assume there are $k$ agents that are learning a labelling function $f^{*} \in \mathcal{H}$ of Hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$ and observe a distinct data distribution $D_i,\; i \in [k]$.

Now, the idea for cooperative learning is quite intuitive. If you find a good candidate hypothesis that has observed $m_{\epsilon/4,\delta}$ samples over average distribution $D=(1/k)\Sigma_{i\in[k]}D_i$ there will be atleast $k/2$ agents that have error less than $\epsilon/2$ which can be seen if you apply markov with expectation being $\epsilon k / 4$.

Now, here is the part where I am stuck. We ask all the agents by passing a set of $O(\frac{1}{\epsilon}log(\frac{|N|}{\epsilon\delta}))$ samples if their error is lower than $3\epsilon/4$. Here $N$ is set of agents at each iteration which are not pruned.

> The authors assert that if the risk $err_{D_i}(f)\leq\epsilon/2$ then
> empirical risk for the test sample cannot be greater than
> $3\epsilon/4$ and if a agent has empirical risk less than
> $3\epsilon/4$ then true risk is less than $\epsilon$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $R_T$ be the true risk and $R_E$ be the empirical risk then we know from VC theorem.

$$
|R_T-R_E| \leq \frac{1}{\delta}\frac{4+\sqrt{dlog(2em/d)}}{\sqrt{2m}}
$$
Here $m$ is the number of samples and $d$ is the VCdim.

A further simplification would be
$$
|R_T-R_E| \leq \frac{1}{\delta}\sqrt{\frac{dlog(2em/d)}{2m}}
$$

assuming $\sqrt{d}>>4$ which is a fair assumption. Now, following the line of reasoning from "Understanding machine learning" shai-shalev book chapter on VC dimension, I get

$$m\geq O(\frac{1}{\epsilon^2\delta^2})$$ which is much bigger than the sample size of samples we initially used. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: To understand your question better: each agent learns its own unique $\hat f_i$ from the data $D_i$? Also, what exactly is this average distribution $D$? I find it quite unusual to average on the distribution, since it has the effect of lowering the inherent distribution's standard deviation (which means that $D$ is drawn from a different distribution than any of the $D_i$s). In practical terms, it means that if you learn over $D$ when $k$ is large enough, you will learn to label only one point approximately. Therefore I would like to know what exactly is $D$ used for in this process, thanks

Comment: each agent learns its own unique ̂  from the data ? Yes

Comment: what exactly is this average distribution ? This is a good question. Each distribution is essentially PDF over the input space $\mathcal{X}$, So when I say average, you are thinking in the right direction. If there is a common subset of $A\subset X$ that has non zero probability according to all $D_i$ then that subset will be boosted in probability in distribution $D$. Also, I forgot to add the assumption is $k\sim O(d)$ that is number of agents is upper-bounded by VC dimension so it can't be too large.

Comment: A more subtle but valid implicit data distribution assumption is that a lot of the same data that is being observed by each agent. For example, multiple self-driving cars are observing sensor information and the probability of observing a car on the road for all cars is higher than observing a plant for example.

Comment: Cool, glad to know you figured it out by yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

So, I realized this because these are $\epsilon/4$-representative samples or
$$
|R_E-R_T| <= \epsilon/4
$$
by construction.
So, if empirical error $3\epsilon/4$ given true error is at most $\epsilon/2$. We can say true error is at most $\epsilon$ if estimated error is $3\epsilon/4$.